# Laravel eloquent where defined value is between json range value in database

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a age range value in the database (MySQL) saved as json array `[25, 35]`
What I need is to filter out records based on defined age, e.g. 31.

So the query should check if 31 is between 25 and 35.

I've tried this:

```
$query->whereJsonContains('age', [31])
```

But unfortunately, this will check if the json contains value **31** and therefore will return false.

Any ideas?

Comment: what driver are you using for your database?

Comment: @IGP I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Can you show a row to see just how the json column is structured?

Comment: @IGP it's a `json` type column and the data inside is literally `[25, 35]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution, therefore, after using `Eloquent` with available filter options I had to use an additional `array_filter`:

```
$query = array_filter($query->all(), function ($post) use($rules) {
    return ($rules['age'] >= $post['age'][0] || $rules['age'] <= $post['age'][1])
});
```